# TypeError: $(...).addClass(...).dataTable is not a function

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have an error trying to add DataTable plugin to my project.
It looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5f5931591f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example')
        .addClass('nowrap')
        .dataTable({
          responsive: true,
          columnDefs: [{
            targets: [-1, -3],
            className: 'dt-body-right'
          }]
        });
    });
  </script>
  <script src="js/plugins/plugins.js"></script>
  <script src="js/assan.custom.js"></script>
  <!-- load cubeportfolio -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cubeportfolio/js/jquery.cubeportfolio.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error. I'm loading datatable js file after jquery file.

Can someone help me?

Kind regards,

Comment: Try `.DataTable()` instead of `.dataTable()`

Comment: It doesn't work for you because you've only included the Datatables.responsive extension, not the core Datatables library itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.0/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Name</th><th>Position</th><th>Office</th><th>Age</th><th>Start date</th><th>Salary</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>Tiger Nixon</td><td>System Architect</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>61</td><td>2011/04/25</td><td>$320,800</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Garrett Winters</td><td>Accountant</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>63</td><td>2011/07/25</td><td>$170,750</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Ashton Cox</td><td>Junior Technical Author</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>66</td><td>2009/01/12</td><td>$86,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Cedric Kelly</td><td>Senior Javascript Developer</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>22</td><td>2012/03/29</td><td>$433,060</td></tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr><th>Name</th><th>Position</th><th>Office</th><th>Age</th><th>Start date</th><th>Salary</th></tr>
        </tfoot>
     </table>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example')
            .addClass('nowrap')
            .dataTable({
                responsive: true,
                columnDefs: [
                    { targets: [-1, -3], className: 'dt-body-right' }
                ]
            });
    });
</script>
<!-- load cubeportfolio -->
</body>
</html>
```

It works for me. I have changed the head.